# SmartWirelessHeadset Pro Icon

Tags: android, sony, headset

(I've created an Android/Extension app for Sony SmartWatch and now I'm adding support for Sony Smart Wireless Headset Pro as well.)

My problem is that the Black & White PNG icon for the Extension is displayed  incorrectly (looks like it's corrupted or something?).

I first thought that it might be a compression error when building the signed application, so I built an unsigned version, replaced the compressed icon with my original icon and then signed it. This did not work, so now I think there might be something wrong with how the headset reads the image?

I've also tried different image color modes (1-bit, 24-bit, 32-bit PNG) all created with The GIMP but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know if there are any specific limitations on this icon (apart from size 18x18px) or if you have to save the file in some special format?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. We will investigate if this is a problem with the Smart Wireless Headset pro software/firmware and if we find anything, I will post more information in this thread.

In general, the [Smart Extension SDK](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tool-guides/download-the-new-smart-extension-sdk-and-create-smart-extras-apps/) contains information about the image formats that are required and recommended. E.g. in the Smart Wireless Headset pro white papers, chapter 2.2. But I guess you have already seen these specifications.

**Update!**

There is a fix for the icon problem available, either from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.smartwirelessheadsetpro) (version 1.0.95) or from the Sony Mobile [support site](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/software/accessories/smart-wireless-headset-pro/). Thanks Peter for pointing this problem out!

Comment: Thank you, I've seen the specs but I don't think they explain why I'm having this problem. Maybe it will be easier if you can have a look at the icon. I've uploaded the icon http://www.codeunlimited.se/tmp/icn_18x18_black_white.png and a photo http://www.codeunlimited.se/tmp/wireless_icon.jpg of how it looks in the wireless headset. It might also be of interest that my project is configured for Android 2.1, using Java 1.6.0_35 (x64). And in Eclipse JUNO the Android SDK Manager shows: Android SDK Tools v20.0.3 and Android SDK Platform-tools 14 among other things. Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, and I'm using the HTC Sensation phone with Smart Connect v4.0.15

Comment: Hey Peter, I've checked out your files, thanks, but I do not have any new information for you at this moment. When (if) I know more, you'll be the first to know, through this thread :).

Comment: Turns out that it's not the app icon which is incorrect/corrupt. In my headset the last icon shown in the app-list it the one which is currupt. To replicate: I have "GPS Map", "GPS Distance" (my app) and "Tally counter" apps enabled. If I disable the tallycounter and enable it again the app is placed as the third app in the Headset list. Now this icon is displayed incorrectly, but my app icon is OK (now as the 2:nd app in the list). It might be that I have a headset from one of the very first batches made, so it might be the headset is broken? Just wanted to let you know, thanks again!